# How do I restore a wallet from a backup file in MultiBit HD?

Tags: wallet, multibit, wallet-recovery

If I have a backup file like `mbhd-*.zip.aes` how do I restore it using only my password? When I click on Restore Wallet, it only asks for the wallet words, not the file path or password.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at "I want to use an existing wallet"?

Comment: Yes, and it only lists the current wallets in the system. It doesn't allow you to choose the file location.

Comment: This ISN'T a duplicate of the other question! That other question is ALSO my question, and it is asking something completely different!

Comment: Going to disagree with @StephenM347. The questions are sufficiently different to reopen. @ Chloe Please try to relate to other users more politely in the future. Speculating on someone's reading ability isn't ok.

Comment: Do you still have your mbhd.wallet.aes file ? You can extract mnemonic seed( words) from it using your password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Security of a MultiBit wallet is broken into four parts:

1. A wallet encrypted by the password but not the wallet words
2. A wallet backup, kept in the cloud, encrypted by the wallet words.
3. "Wallet words," kept on a piece of paper
4. A password, kept in your head.

You have 2 and 4, but not 1 or 3. My understanding is that that's not enough to restore your wallet. If you had your wallet words, or access to the computer that created this wallet, it would be different.

Comment: Oh so the `mbhd-*.zip.aes` files are not the same as what MultiBit uses on a daily basis? Where does it keep the other file encrypted with only the password? How would I restore a wallet from a copy of that file? There still isn't any option to select a file path.

Comment: MultiBit HD dev here. The cloud backups are encrypted with an AES key derived from the wallet words only, not the password.

Comment: @jim618 Hi, thanks for chiming in. Are items 1 and 2 on the above list correct?

Comment: I think this is wrong. The wallet words uniquely determine the wallet. You shouldn't need the wallet words to decrypt the cloud backup.

Comment: @jwg OK. Go make a wallet, restore it without the password, and show that I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, I just did it.

Comment: @jwg I misremembered the asker's question. The asker is asking about restoring from a wallet backup and the wallet password.